# How to multiply all row MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to multiply all row MySQL with PHP

I have database named **count** and the example MySQL table named **tblcount** :

```
|id|number1|number2|result|
|1 |   4   |   1   |      |
|2 |   5   |   4   |      |
|3 |   6   |   3   |      |
```

i want to be :

```
|id|number1|number2|result|
|1 |   4   |   1   |  4   |
|2 |   5   |   4   |  20  |
|3 |   6   |   3   |  18  |
```

i already used this code, but the code is not run correctly :

```
<?php
require 'database/db.php';

$count = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblcount");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count);

$result = $row['number1'] * $row['number2'];

$mysqli->query("UPDATE tblcount
                SET result = '".$result."'");
?>
```

what's the wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply them with in the query. Not only multiple, the other operations also. Try with this -

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE tblcount SET result = (number1 * number2)");
```

If you want to multiply with other table columns then -

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE tblcount tc, tblother to SET tc.result = (to.field1 * to.field2)");
```

Comment: you have missed closing quotes, in both queries

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in sql query, no need of php intraction. Try below Query

```
UPDATE tblcount SET result=number1*number2
```

Comment: But the query would be executed with `php` i think.

Comment: how if i want to multiply with another table example admintbl?

Comment: @AlexandroSetiawan , if your another table `admintbl` has the same columns (number1 and number2) and you want to update  result in `tblcount`, you could simply join both tables and updates result column with calculation as required.